# XAMPP Tomcat shows running but is not. Can't stop Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, xampp

Found an issue where XAMPP control believes tomcat is running but cannot stop it.

The following error can be found in the tomcat logs directory under catalina

"SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the process id from xampp. Go to TaskManager and show process' from all users. Find the process. Right click and open file location. If the file is within an opengeo directory then you likely have opengeo installed. Stopping Opengeo through the start menu resolved the problem for me. Changing the port(s) may be another option (not tested).